# how to split a string twice and add to ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have a single string as follows

```
one two
three
four
```

I would like to split this into an arrayList so that I can get

```
String[] g = [one,two,three,four]
```

I think I need to split by newline and by space but something so simple is defeating me

I have tried:

```
String [] bilbo=null;
List<String> temp=new ArrayList<String>();

bilbo=g.split("\\n|\\r");

for (String d:bilbo) {
    if (d!="") {
        if (d.matches("\\s")) {
            dd = d.split("\\s");
            for (String a : dd) {
                temp.add(a.trim());
            }
        } else {
            temp.add(d.trim());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `matches`.  read the doc for that function.

Comment: `if (d!="") {` -> [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of splitting with `"\n|\r"`, you could simply split with `"\\s+"`, which will cover spaces and new lines:

```
ArrayList<String> list = Arrays.asList(g.split("\\s+"));
```